# single command to stop and remove docker container

Tags: docker

Is there any command which can combine the `docker stop` and `docker rm` command together ? Each time I want to delete a running container, I need to execute 2 commands sequentially, I wonder if there is a combined command can simplify this process.

```
docker stop CONTAINER_ID
docker rm CONTATINER_ID
```

Comment: It depends on the container: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

You can use :

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_ID
```

It will remove the container even if it is still running.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/

You can also run your containers with `--rm` option (e.g. `docker run --rm -it alpine`), it will be automatically removed when stopped.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm

**Edit:** The `rm -f` might be dangerous for your data and is best suited for test or development containers. @Bernard's comment on this subject is worth reading.

Comment: Be careful. `docker rm -f` sends a SIGKILL signal to the container. This may not let the container time to save its state correctly. For non stateless containers one should really use `docker stop` followed by `docker rm`. This sends a SIGTERM signal which by default gives containers a max of 10 secs to perform their shutdown before the docker daemon finally sends a SIGKILL.

Comment: i find --rm option most appropriate for short lived containers.

Answer (score 58):

```
docker stop CONTAINER_ID | xargs docker rm
```

Comment: Clever idea. I like it since it could be used for other commands as well, where you want to pass an argument on two commands without repeating them or using a variable.

Answer (score 32):

You can stop and remove the container with a single command the `$_` gives you the last echo

```
docker stop CONTAINER && docker rm $_
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case, to stop and remove all containers I used

```
 docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

In case you also need to remove the images, then run
`docker rmi $(docker images -q)` afterwards.

**Only** run `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` if you want to remove the images.

Comment: Although pretty obvious, that this also remove images should be stated (and was not part of the question).

Comment: This also removes stopped containers. To remove only the running ones, remove the `-a` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/

You can use kill, and also by using rm and the force flag it will also use kill.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all containers: `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f`

Comment: Got permission denied error. Added sudo. `sudo docker ps -aq | sudo xargs docker rm -f`

Comment: @HussainK you don't need sudo if your account is a member of the docker group.

Answer (score 2):

This will stop and remove all images including running containers as we are using -f

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the docker ps command with the -a flag to locate the name or ID of the containers you want to remove

```
docker ps -a
```

To remove: $ docker rm ID_or_Name ID_or_Name

Remove a container upon exit:

If you know when you’re creating a container that you won’t want to keep it around once you’re done, you can run docker run --rm to automatically delete it when it exits.

Run and Remove : `docker run --rm image_name`

Remove all exited containers:

You can locate containers using docker ps -a and filter them by their status: created, restarting, running, paused, or exited. To review the list of exited containers, use the -f flag to filter based on status. When you've verified you want to remove those containers, using -q to pass the IDs to the docker rm command.

List:

```
docker ps -a -f status=exited

docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
```

**Remove containers using more than one filter**:

Docker filters can be combined by repeating the filter flag with an additional value. This results in a list of containers that meet either condition. For example, if you want to delete all containers marked as either Created (a state which can result when you run a container with an invalid command) or Exited, you can use two filters:

```
docker ps -a -f status=exited -f status=created
```

Stop and Remove all the containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all stopped containers `docker system prune`

To stop live container, `docker stop CONTAINER_ID` waits 10 sec and it calls `docker kill CONTAINER_ID`

Or with `docker kill CONTAINER_ID`, you can immediately stop the container

Answer (score 1):

When using docker for development, which is the only thing I use docker for, I build, run and cleanup like this.

```
docker build -t latest . && docker run -p 4000:4000 latest && docker system prune -f
```

This one-liner, executed in a directory with docker configured, does three things.

1. It builds the docker image
2. It runs it
3. And then it cleans up

When doing development, I don't care about any docker images or containers that I'm not currently using, so this works for me.

The way I do it though, it is heavy-handed. The **system prune** command wipes out all unused images, containers, and other resources associated with previous builds.

[docker system prune documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

There's also **docker container prune** that will only remove unused containers, that might be more appropriate, depending on how you use docker.

[docker container prune documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)

Running all three of the above commands on one line, separated by double ampersands, and not putting a -d on the docker run command, means that the **system prune** will happen when the **docker run** is stopped via the command line with a control-c.

To learn more about shell scripting and what **&&** does, the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

For removing a single container

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_ID
```

For removing all containers

```
docker rm -f `docker container ps -qa`
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all container with xargs

```
docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
```

for stop all

```
sudo docker ps -a -q |sudo  xargs docker stop
```

remove single container

```
docker rm -f <container_id>
```