# docker stop and remove container

Tags: docker

This is a very basic question. One can stop and remove a docker container like this.

```
docker stop <container_id>
docker rm <container_id>
```

Is it the same as this?

```
docker rm -f <container_id>
```

If they are not the same, what are the negative effects of using the latter?

I already saw [single command to stop and remove docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122773/single-command-to-stop-and-remove-docker-container). But it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are similar you can check the man pages:

```
Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

  -f, --force        Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
```

and

```
Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Stop a running container.
Sending SIGTERM and then SIGKILL after a grace period

  --help             Print usage
  -t, --time=10      Seconds to wait for stop before killing it
```

I would say

```
docker stop <container_id>
docker rm <container_id>
```

would be a little more "graceful" since it sends first a `SIGTERM` prior to `SIGKILL` this would give docker a chance to clean things up.

Comment: I was thinking the same about gracefulness. Thank you.

Comment: I found the <container_id> on the docker app.